# How to resolve ASP.NET.Core 2 Package restoration related warning and errors

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

Whenever I start a .NET CORE 2 web App Project **With** Authentication (i.e. Individual Authentication) I get the following warning:

> Package 'Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27' was restored using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

The issue doesn't stop here, I am trying to install  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` and I get the following error:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for project

I tried the following, ALL Failed!

1. Deleting `Nuget.Config`
2. I added `<PropertyGroup> <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet</PackageTargetFallback>   </PropertyGroup>`
3. restore packages via `dotnet restore`
4. Clear Nuget Cache (from Tools>NuGet>Package Manager Settings)

How can I resolve this conflict?

this is my project file

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
    <UserSecretsId></UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and a snapshot from my screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency issues have been resolved by adding in .csproj and updating the following packages using `NuGet`,

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Composition" Version="1.0.27" ExcludeAssets="All" />  
<PackageReference Include="System.Composition" Version="1.0.31" />
```

The .csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
    <UserSecretsId>***********</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Composition" Version="1.0.31" ExcludeAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Composition" Version="1.1.0-preview2-25405-01" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[Ref](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18452), [Ref2](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22991#issuecomment-320559736)